# Applying a change to every line?

Tags: vim, gvim

How to add 4 spaces to every line between marks (bound with m-letter and current line). How to do the same when using visual block?

Comment: Can you give a sample file and expected output?

Comment: Oops, good answers below but to wrong question. Reg.expressions below can easily be modified to the need to add spaces to the left-ends of lines of code by using carot instead of dollar-sign. This usually occurs when copying a block of code from an example to the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:'x,.s/$/    /
```

Would add 4 spaces at the end of the lines between mark `x` and the current line.

In visual mode, you can press `:` which will bring `:'<,'>` and then add `s/$/    /` to add 4 spaces to the end of each line in that selection.

If you want to add 4 spaces at the right edge of the currently selected visual block, just enter `A`, enter those 4 spaces and <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a substitute command

```
:%s/m/&    /
```

you can add some flags at the end to apply things multiple times to one line (`g`), or confirm the substitution (`c`).

The `%` before `s` will apply changes to the entire file. If you want a block you can do something like

```
:.,+4s/m/&    /
```

This will search from the current line (`.`) down, for the next 4 (`+4`) lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search and replace with the right pattern matching. Something like (untested):

```
:%/m.*$/m    $1/g
```

In visual mode, you can use ctrl+v to define a region.  An edit will be duplicated in all selected blocks.